# Python: tkinter window presented in an OO manner

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have been trying to represent tkinter window in an OO manner. There are few answers here, and I have managed to produce a working code, but I simply do not understand why it's working.

```
import tkinter as tk
class CurrConv:
    def __init__(self, window, date):
        self.window = window
        window.title("Currency Converter")
        window.geometry("350x150+300+300")

        self.label = tk.Label(text="Date: {}\n".format(date))
        self.label.pack()

        self.text_box = tk.Text()
        self.text_box.insert("2.0", "100 is: {}\n".format(100))
        self.text_box.insert("3.0", "24  is: {}".format(24))
        self.text_box.pack()

        self.button = tk.Button(text="Quit", width=8, command=window.quit)
        self.button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.9, anchor="center",)


def main():
    window = tk.Tk()
    app = CurrConv(window, 1234)
    window.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The thing I don't understand is the usage of "app" object. It is used nowhere, and usually when we create an object (in any programing language), we invoke certain actions on it. However here we do nothing with the app object. Class encapsulation appears to indirectly modify "window", which is confusing, to say the least.

Next, I don't understand how labels and text boxes are added to "window", when in the code I nowhere create those in "window", I create them on "self", which would be "app", which is no longer used.

Bottom line is, for the reasons above, I do not understand how the above code works.

Thanks in advance.
I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: The code is a bad example.  It is better to specify the master when creating widgets.  Also the two lines `window.title(...)` and `window.geometry(...)` should not be called inside the class because `window` is an external object passed to it, it is better not to alter it except it is by purpose.  The `app` variable is necessary in some scenario in order to avoid the instance of the class from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Class encapsulation appears to indirectly modify "window", which is confusing, to say the least.

Yes, that is what the code is doing, and it's incorrect IMHO. The code inside of `CurrConv.__init__` at least arguably should not be directly modifying the root window for some of the very reasons you put in your question.

> Next, I don't understand how labels and text boxes are added to "window", when in the code I nowhere create those in "window", I create them on "self", which would be "app", which is no longer used.

Your terminology is a bit incorrect. "I nowhere create those in 'window'" isn't true. By creating the widgets without an explicit master they default to being created in the root window. The *reference* to the widget is created in the class (`self.label`, etc) but the widget itself is created in the root window. IMHO this is also not the proper way to write a tkinter application. Explicit is better than implicit.

---

For me, the proper way to write this class would be for `CurrConv` to inherit from a tkinter `Frame` (or some other widget). Everything it creates should go inside itself, and then the code that creates the instance of `CurrConv` is responsible for adding it to a window. This solves your problem of not being able to create multiple windows.

Also, the widgets inside of `CurrConv` should explicitly set the master of any child widgets it creates rather than relying on a default master.

Example:

```
class CurrConv(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, window, date):
        super().__init__(window)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, ...)
        self.text_box = tk.Text(self, ...)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, ...)
        ...
    ...
```

With that, everything is nicely encapsulated inside the class, and you can create multiple instances inside multiple windows very easily:

```
root = tk.Tk()
conv1 = CurrConv(root)
conv1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

top = tk.Toplevel(root)
conv2 = CurrConv(top)
conv2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

In the above case, it's perfectly fine for the class to modify the window because it's part of the code that creates the window in the first place.

You can still use a class for the application as a whole which you can use to hold some global state. To further prove the usefulness of creating `CurrConv` as a subclass of `Frame`, the following example adds currency converters to a notebook instead of separate windows.

```
class CurrConvApp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Currency Converter")
        self.root.geometry("350x150+300+300")

        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.root)
        cc1 = CurrConv(self.notebook)
        cc2 = CurrConv(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(cc1, text="USD to EUR")
        self.notebook.add(cc2, text="EUR to USD")
        ...

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = CurrConvApp()
    app.start()
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your detailed answer. I basically went on to copy paste it and well, learn it. But, this is either a bad example for using classes, or I keep missing something. Even in your solution we keep modifying global ("window") and when I run the code, when I pass "self" in creating label for instance, it does not create it window.

While I did learn some stuf here, I think I will just refrain from using OO here, as it seems to overcomplicate stuff, for a small app...

Comment: @MilosMirosavljevic I fixed a mistake in the last block of code. Nothing in any of my examples keep modifying the global `window` object. Other than my mistake of using `window` instead of `self.root` in the final example, this is the simplest way to use OO programming with tkinter. I've written tens of thousands of lines of code using these techniques.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, yes `app` is an object. But it is an instance of the class `CurrConv`. When you initialize a class, you call the class's `__init__` method, and this case, by doing so, you execute the statements in that method: modifying the window (which you passed as a parameter whin you created `app`) and adding widgets to it. So although `app` is not directly used, it had the side effect of doing those things when it was created. And for that reason, since you only need the initialization method, assigning to a variable is not necessary, you can just make it like `CurrConv(window, 1234)`.

For the second, yes, you didn't mention `window` when you created the widgets, but when the master of a new Tkinter widget is not specified, it takes the main master (the root, created using `tk.Tk()`) as it's master.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it does make a things more clear. But still, the whole class encapsulation seems a bit redundant then? If I am not using the object created from it, I cannot create more objects (different windows) by using the same blueprint class?
It looks like I have global variable (window) and I created class which indirectly modified this variable (function can do the same). And I cannot use differnet objects. 

This solution is basically copy-paste from this site, I am just trying to understand its value.

Comment: If your goal is to make just a simple small window with a few widgets in it (like the currency converter), you can do away without classes and objects. You can just move the contents of the `__init__` method to `main`, tweak it to make it work and you're good to go. But if you want to make a big application which will have many parts, using classes and objects is recommended as it makes it easy to organize your code into components, and I think your original code is a good starting point for that.

Comment: Again, thanks for the fast reply. Originally code was indeed in main, but I wanted it to make it with classes. I have then found this solution here, but I still don't understand it, as it essentially makes useless object and it doesn't allow more objects to be made, which is, correct me if I'm wrong, the whole purpose of making a class in the first place.

But ok, this may be afteral a bad example altogether.

Comment: More objects _can_ be created, I don't know why you'd think you can't do that. You create classes to have some sort of hierarchy. For an example you can look at https://github.com/K1DV5/docal-tkinter/blob/master/docal_tkinter/sidebar.py (my own)

Comment: Hey, here I am again. Yes, more objects can be created, but in this case objects themselves are not used. We agreed that class encapsulation ih this case serves only the purpose to indirectly modify "window". That's what I am trying to say. Usually we have something like class Car, and then more obejcts like Fors and Nissan, but in this case various objects would not mean anything. I hope I was clear enough.

In the example you have, you inherrit class from Frame, so it makes sense. In mine it does not.

Comment: Oh I see. Well in that case I agree, for your example it doesn't make sense. It's just more boilerplate.